# Can you use named parameters with an OdbcCommand?

Tags: .net, asp.net, database, odbc

I have a query like this:

```
string command = @"SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt,
(
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attend
        WHERE (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,start_date) = 2 OR DATEPART(WEEKDAY,start_date) = 6)
            AND empl_no = ? and pay_code = '051'
                AND start_date BETWEEN ? AND ?
        ) as frimon
FROM attend as a
WHERE empl_no = ? and pay_code = '051'";
```

The only way I can figure out to specify a Parameter is with a `?` (as opposed to using the `@name` method with a SQLCommand).  This is forcing me to specify the same parameter multiple times (like for `empl_no`).  Is there a way to use named parameters with OdbcCommands so I can just specify a named parameter once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no.  One way around this would be to roll your own class where you can define your own parameter collection and use token replacement.

Comment: be careful when rolling your own code to replace named parameters  that you don't introduce the potential for SQL injection attacks http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection